# Sync command for OpenStack Object Storage (like S3 Sync)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, openstack, openstack-swift

Using the S3 CLI, I can sync a local directory with an S3 bucket using the following command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/ ./local_dir/
```

This command is a complete sync.  It uploads new files, updates changed files, and deletes removed files.  I am trying to figure out how to do something equivalent using the OpenStack Object Storage CLI:

http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/swiftclient_commands.html

The `upload` command has a `--changed` option.  But I need a complete sync that is also capable of deleting local files that were removed.

Does anyone know if I can do something equivalent to s3 sync?

Comment: I know this is old but if you are looking to use Openstack Swift then you can enable S3 Emulator (Swift3 middleware) so you can use `s3cmd` tool just like your existing command. `s3cmd sync s3://mybucket/ ./local_dir/`

Answer (score 0):

The link you mentioned has this :

`

```
objects –

A list of file/directory names (strings) or SwiftUploadObject instances containing a source for the created object, an object name, and an options dict (can be None) to override the options for that individual upload operation`
```

I'm thinking, if you pass the directory and the --changed option it should work.
I don't have a swift to test with. Can you try again?